# How to declare variables in css

Tags: css

Can anyone tell me why it is declared var(--color), what is the difference in declaring only the variable?

Ex:

```css
color: var(--color, var(--blue));
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use the variable without `var` you set the value to the variable

```css
:root {
  --color: red; /* set a value "red" to the "color" variable */
}
```

If you want then to get a value from the variable, you need to use `var`:

```css
.card {
  color: var(--color);  /* get a color from the "--color" variable */
}
```

From the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties):

> Custom properties (sometimes referred to as CSS variables or cascading
> variables) are entities defined by CSS authors that contain specific
> values to be reused throughout a document. They are set using custom
> property notation (e.g., --main-color: black;) and are accessed using
> the var() function (e.g., color: var(--main-color);).

An example:

```css
:root {
  --color: red; /* set default value for "color" variable */
}


#primary-cards {
  --color: #0F0; /* set custom value for "color" variable in primary cards */
}

.card {
  color: var(--color);  /* use the color variable */
}
```

```html
<section id="primary-cards">
  <div class='card'>
    My card content
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  :root{
       /* --color: rbg)1,2,3,4);  error code, or --color variable doesn't exist */
      --blue: blue;
      
      --display-color: red;
      --NoFallBack-to-blue: blue;
      
      }
      
   .red{
      color: var(--display-color, var(--NoFallBack-to-blue))
      }
      
   .blue{
      color: var(--color, var(--blue))
      }
     
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="red">
  <p> color will not fallback to blue </p>
</div>


<div class="blue">
  <p> color will fallback to blue </p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

My bad, I didn't read the question, I only read the css code.

You can create a block of css root and assign a value to the declared variable.

For example:

```
:root {

   --color: rgb(53, 52, 52); 


  /* for fall back */
  --blue: #0000FF;
}
```

Inside a css selector, let's call the variable

```
.className{
   
    color: var(--color);
}
```

lets say `--color` doesn't exist or forgot to assign a value to the variable.

```
:root {

       --color: ; 
  
    
      /* for fall back */
      --blue: #0000FF;
    }
```

It is a fallback when first value doesn't work out then the program will fallback to next value which is `--blue`. The var(--blue) will display on the screen

```
.className{

    color: --var(--color, var(--blue))
}
```

Comment: To complete the answer, you should show how it's used as well.  Maybe show an example of another value than colour as well.

Comment: *You must declare variable inside a root.* --> this is false

Comment: I understand, but my question is about var(--color, I've seen it in several tutorials and I didn't find information on google

Comment: @RohitGupta how's the example? let me know if it needs to improve. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @TemaniAfif I replaced the answer since the answer didn't match the question